# Header carousel is not showing

Tags: html, css, dom, carousel, owl-carousel

I use the plugin owl carousel to make the header of my page, but the background only appear when i write with a h1 tag, without the h1 tag only  my navbar appears, i followed video tutorials and still not working, code below.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
           <div style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) ), url(img/slider/foto_1.jpg)"><h1>hi</h1></div>
           <div style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) ), url(img/slider/foto_2.jpg)"> </div>
   </div>
```

[image: only show the background with h1 and the navbar below is white]

Comment: Because without the `h1` tag there is no element in the `div`, which means the height of `div` becomes zero thus not visible. Add some element to the div at it should show. :)

Comment: i saw this on the website but i wanna use the background because of the linear gradient and i dont know what element i can use. In this video he use like i code [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_13TpioqCaE)